# Rally c# API - convert DynamicJsonObject to a class object

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, rally

I am building my own app to talk to the Rally API.

What i have is the [Rally c# SDK](http://rallytools.github.io/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/html/3ef29523-65cb-43dc-a962-3690be4915cd.htm) installed and have converted the JSON responses into strongly typed classes.

I am converting them by:

1. Getting the [dynamicJsonObject](http://rallytools.github.io/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/html/6fa4730e-44b9-c371-b929-55a3e7c0459e.htm)
2. Converting it to a Dictionary
3. Serializing the Dictionary to JSON
4. Deserializing the JSON into my class.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
 var taskRequest = new Request()
    {
        ArtifactName = "task",
        Query = new Query("WorkProduct.OID", Query.Operator.Equals, userstory.ObjectID.ToString())
    };
    QueryResult queryTaskResult = api.Query(taskRequest);
    if (queryTaskResult.TotalResultCount > 0)
    {
        foreach (DynamicJsonObject result in queryTaskResult.Results)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.ToDictionary());
            var task = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RallyDataTypes.Task>(json);
            userstory.TaskList.Add(task);
        }
    }
```

This 'works' but it feels very inefficient and is slow to load on bigger user stories.

**Question:**

Is there a 'better' / 'right' way to do this? I ask as i've not had to work with these dataTypes before.

Cheers

**EDIT:**
Some of the answers have been to use JSON.net. I am currently using this to do my converts, my question is more specifically to do with the Type the Rally SDK returns to me, i do not have access to the raw JSON as it's abstracted away from me.

Type clarifications

```
DynamicJsonObject  = A type from the Rally SDK
queryTaskResult.Results = IEnumerable<dynamic>
result = DynamicJsonObject
```

Comment: I would recommend you try out the JSON.net library or similar.  You just call something along the liines of `Serialize(YourObject)` or `YourObject = Deserialize<YourClass>(json)`

Comment: Almost all .NET projects use Json.NET. You should be getting an object ready for use, not the obsolete DynamicJsonObject . Do you have a link to that SDK? Perhaps there's a newer version or the SDK is no longer used

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` directly on the returned JSON string, and convert it into the desired class. No need for the dictionary.

```
var task = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RallyDataTypes.Task>(queryTaskResult.Results);
userstory.TaskList.Add(task);
```

It will take care of matching JSON object fields into their respective properties in C#.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately, `queryTaskResult.Results`  returns an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, it is not JSON. :(

Comment: @MrGiggles, I have researched a bit, and it looks like this `DynamicJsonObject` is a bit obsolete, and there is no direct method that support deserializing from it. I guess your way is correct.

Comment: Thanks Ghasan, have you got any links to the things you researched?

Comment: There is probably a better way to do this using the latest .NET tech.  The toolkit was conceived many moons ago and this was the best we could do at that time.  I think the dynamic capabilities and dealing with JSON in general have come quite a way since then.

Comment: @MrGiggles, if you see the ASP.NET stack, and it's dealings with JSON, you will realize that even namespaces like System.Web.MVC relies of JSON.NET, not JsonDynamicObject